# How to refine a string to a "string enum" in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Take this simple example of a string enum:

```
enum Animal {
  Dog = "Dog",
  Cat = "Cat",
  Sheep = 'Sheep'
}

const getNoise = (animal: Animal) => {
  switch (animal) {
    case Animal.Dog:
      return 'woof';
    case Animal.Cat:
      return 'meow';
    case Animal.Sheep:
      return 'baa';
  }
}
```

But let's say I want to make another function that processes an arbitrary `string`, originating from untrusted user input. The string *should* be a valid `Animal`, but it might contain typos, so we need to validate it at runtime.

Here's an example:

```
const getNoiseUntrusted = (animal: string) => {
  if (!(animal in Animal)) {
    throw new Error('Animal not recognised');
  }

  return getNoise(animal); // TypeScript error
}
```

The `getNoise(animal)` call causes a TypeScript error:

`Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Animal'.`

How can I get TypeScript to cast this string to an `Animal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting with `as` works:

```
const getNoiseUntrusted = (animal: string) => {
  if (!(animal in Animal)) {
    throw new Error('Animal not recognised');
  }
  return getNoise(animal as Animal);
}
```

You can also expand on the switch in your regular getter, since you'd be checking the input string against the value of the specific enums.

```
const getNoiseUntrustedSwitch = (animal: string) => {
  switch (animal) {
    case Animal.Dog:
      return 'woof';
    case Animal.Cat:
      return 'meow';
    case Animal.Sheep:
      return 'baa';
    default: 
    throw new Error('Animal not recognised');
  }
}
```

And finally, to build on @Daniel's answer, you can also cast while accessing the enum:

```
const getNoiseUntrustedEnumAcess = (animal: string) => {
  if (!(animal in Animal)) {
    throw new Error('Animal not recognised');
  }
  return getNoise(Animal[animal as Animal]);
}
```

See on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-f6A4GgiFQmFwtAgRHJYAotEHTEu2a0lQMwmrEmsnZ7fZg8AQGBKYBqNRHfyC86Xa63XgPZ78tAfMPfOUhP4A0GB8GQwjQ2H+BFI6MkWMYrG8WZGhoElbEwzGMMAbRl8MpYYAuqO5rjUMAkqxjNPmRn2Qcc5B84W1MZqCRKN9sdvd-umemtpmOfsuZKBFebbeNw+9wPF82SzK8uD-bFtgATzFACnzTDZX2PfYrwAIWEVgUGACD5BKHlfGAH5gjgwiaRwaDYKwx8gMQkD30-Hk0IwrCcLmPCpWMQjmxIjdZgooI4JolkkKzU88wLIsmO0Fi71wsJ8M4oi8B4mkgA)

Although note that this is case-sensitive, so you may need to modify user input slightly before checking whether or not it is part of the enum.

Answer (score 2):

`Animal["Dog"]` will return "Dog"

`Animal["Puppy"]` will return undefined

---

```
const getNoiseUntrusted = (animal: string) => {
    if(!Animal[animal]){
        throw new Error('Animal not recognised');
    }
}
```

Comment: No sorry, your code doesn't fix my error, and it adds a new type error too. Try it in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAgiCWECGAbKBvAsAKClAIgPYDmUAvFAERHGUA0OeAwkgC7lUuv2NQDKAC2DAADhwDkg4SPE4AvjhwBjQiADO7YsFYA5QvDXAOACiQJkKAFyxzqAJTkAfBl5qA7vFZKBUU7ZQOWLh4UEpIhjaIqAB0NJa8IVAATtpgSSBQ4m6EhABm4gDcCaHhRnBRKNFc8cGJKaxpGeIQwIRuhcVhEeUW0VKiNYl49Y2ZAEZISB3BCtizyqoaUFq6+oYAqiCsSWAawAAmJmYV1hpJ8CDEDmTOQXjwucYAhD2oANrHFgC6dnchrAIkm0oCBgG4oABRJJApLGcSvNAgQjsFIqYgIQz7cR2IozRTBEbpZbaPQGYB+Co4+Q4IA)

Comment: @Daniel: You forgot the cast: `if(!Animal[animal as Animal]){
        throw new Error('Animal not recognised');
    }`